# Prevent a server side script from a direct URL access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

There is a server side script written in php(say backend_file.php) or coldfusion(say backend_file.cfm).

Lets say, i am using Apache and I have a sample web folder (on my Localhost) like:

- backend_file.php
- index.php

Is it possible to restrict access of backend_file.php, when directly hit from browser?

**However, index.php should be able to access backend_file.php?**

Note: index.php is accessible, by direct URL access.

I mentioned index.php should be able to access backend_file.php, as it makes ajax post or get request to fetch information from backend_file.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to send a forbidden code when a certain file is requested. Put this in a .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^backend_file\.php$ - [F,L]
```

Alternativelly, you can use the Deny directive. Put a .htaccess file in the directory that contains this file and add:

```
<Files "backend_file.php">
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rely on `HTTP_REFERER` for this since you are making `HTTP` request to backend file from `index.php`. You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/index\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^backend_file\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Replace `domain.com` with your actual domain name.